# UPDATE multiple Columns in SSMS/T-SQL:

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I have the following scenario.

```
 UPDATE ATable
SET C1 = 'XValue'
WHERE C2 = 'YValue'

UPDATE ATable
SET C3 = 'MValue'
WHERE C4 = 'NValue'
```

For performance tuning, can I do anything to make them run under one UPDATE? Would it be better?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can run one update using `CASE`

```
UPDATE  Atable
SET     C1 = CASE WHEN c2 = 'yValue' THEN 'xValue' ELSE c1 END,
        C3 = CASE WHEN c4 = 'nvalue' THEN 'mValue' ELSE c3 END
WHERE   c2 = 'yValue' OR c4 = 'nvalue'
```

Comment: @AndriyM yes, with `WHERE` clause.

Comment: That was the OP's question, not mine.

Comment: @njk why would you think so?

Comment: @KennethFisher Also depends on indexes.

Comment: @njk assuming that there are indexes defined, why is it not performance wise? so you mean it is better to have two scan (*for two update statement*) than one scan but with using `CASE`?

Comment: Depends on what indexes are available. If `c2` and `c4` are indexed you could be replacing 2 seeks with a full scan.

Comment: @MartinSmith if that's the case, what indexes should be define? Is it right to have compound index on `c2, c4`?

Comment: @CommanderOnets If both columns are reasonably selective then two separate indexes on the individual columns would be best just considering the 2 update statements in isolation.

Comment: This update is on temp table/columns and none of those four columns have any indexes. Would it be better to perform multiple updates by using CASE?